# python nested classes with adjacent inheritence?

Tags: python, inheritance, nested, nested-class

```
class A(object):
    class B(object): pass
    class C(A.B): pass
```

results in

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

How do I inherit from `B` in `C`, if they are *adjacent* , both nested in `A` (inner classes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `A` until the class body has finished executing.

You *can* refer to 'local' names; the class body is executed as a function, and the local namespace of that function is used to supply the class attributes; within the class body, `B` is a local name:

```
class A(object):
    class B(object): pass
    class C(B): pass
```